# How to replace an image with same name but different type of another image in a folder?

Tags: c#

Suppose i have a folder and in this folder is an image named `im1.png`. i want that `im1.png` is deleted when i save another image named `im1.jpg` or `im1.bmp` or so on...(same name but different type) in this folder. i write following code but this code just delete file that has same name and same type. Help me please...

```
string CopyPic(string MySourcePath, string key, string imgNum)
    {
        string curpath;
        string newpath;

        curpath = Application.Current + @"\FaceDBIMG\" + key;

        if (Directory.Exists(curpath) == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(curpath);

        newpath = curpath + "\\" + imgNum + MySourcePath.Substring(MySourcePath.LastIndexOf("."));

        string[] similarFiles = Directory.GetFiles(curpath, imgNum + ".*").ToArray();

        foreach (var similarFile in similarFiles)
            File.Delete(similarFile);

        File.Copy(MySourcePath, newpath);

        return newpath;
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you don't need to check for `Directory.Exists(curpath)`, just call `Directory.CreateDirectory(curpath);` every time, if the directory already exists the function does nothing (well, it actually returns the `DirectoryInfo` object for the existing directory, but you are not using the result of the function, so for your use case it does nothing).

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain : thanks, i edited my question. and this code make a  check whether a file already exists or not. my problem is with file not with directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
string filename = ...; //e.g. c:\directory\filename.ext

//Get the directory where the file lives
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);

//Get the filename without the extension to use it to search the directory for similar files
string filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

//Search the directory for files with same name, but with any extension
//We use the Except method to remove the file it self form the search results
string[] similarFiles =
    Directory.GetFiles(dir, filenameWithoutExtension + ".*")
    .Except(
        new []{filename},
        //We should ignore the case when we remove the file itself
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToArray();

//Delete these files
foreach(var similarFile in similarFiles)
    File.Delete(similarFile);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I made some changes in your answer but i have following Exception! your answer seems right but i don't know why i have an Exception!! i edited my question with this code. please see that.
`("The process cannot access the file 'E:\FaceAuthentication\FaceApp\bin\Debug\FaceApp.App\FaceDBIMG\23\5.jpg' because it is being used by another process.") `