# How to mass import/update Android drawables (in PNG format) and overwrite previously converted WEBP drawables?

Tags: android, assets, drawable

I have approximately 100+ drawables in my Android project, and recently received updates to 33 of the drawables in PNG format. Normally my workflow is to merge/replace the drawable-... folders to replace drawables that have updates, and retain other drawables that do not need to be updated. This works well when the files are of the same type (all PNG), but recently in an effort to slim down the app, we converted in AS the entire drawable directory to WEBP (lossless). Now when I do merge and replace with updated assets, both PNG and WEBP versions of the same drawables are retained, which causes build failures on every duplicate drawable.

I have tried the "Convert to WEBP" option in AS on the entire merged drawable directory, but this does not attempt to convert the drawables that have existing WEBP files, leaving duplicates all over.

Any suggestions on solutions (aside from manual remove, replace, rename, etc on individual files) would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I am asking the design team if they can just give us WEBP files instead, but they are on vacation this week so I was hoping for another way!

Comment: Try Build -> clean project, now I will try to solve your problem, I hope

Comment: Thanks KKKKK, unfortunately that did not solve my problem, there are still the duplicate resources.

Comment: ok I found it, now I will post the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found this type of solution, I hope this goes well for you.

Instead of put new images with webp extension inside the drawable folder, why dont you convert the png images in webp images inside android studio?

This is what you have to do:

- select all your images at once
- right mouse click
- convert to webp
- now please attention: uncheck only the "skip images with transparency/alpha channel...",
  the rest leave it unchanged
- click next for your N images and click finish

now you have replaced all your PNG images with WEBp images

hope this works well for you

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. That is the workflow I did originally in AS (Android Studio) to convert all assets to WEBP. Then I received updates to 33 of the assets (with same names) but in PNG format. My issue is how to replace the 33 older WEBP versions of these drawables with the new PNG drawables I received.

Comment: @Notlaw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153392/how-to-replace-an-image-with-same-name-but-different-type-of-another-image-in-a try this solution then

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that does not involve code like that, but could be done in Android Studio. Thanks.